# Why I can't download and save image from Discogs?

Tags: node.js

Why I can't create file from the second link? The response is coming, but the file is created with an error. What's wrong with discogs? Do they block such requests?

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var link1 = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/df/a0/5c/dfa05ce90cbcbc47c8837e9172948dfc.jpg";
var link2 = "https://img.discogs.com/swlUq29dib4kEyctdxO38RDwDrc=/fit-in/600x594/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-1111653-1477834177-2042.jpeg.jpg";

var file1 = fs.createWriteStream("file1.jpg");
var request = https.get(link1, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file1);
});

var file2 = fs.createWriteStream("file2.jpg");
var request = https.get(link2, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file2);
});
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/w1549x file is not created.

Comment: Did you try to subscribe to `error` and `end` events of `file2` stream?

Comment: no errors. process finished, but file is incorrect((

Comment: I suppose your process simply didn't wait until file writing is finished.